# Make logo dynamic in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I have a problem with my wordpress site logo. I cannot make the site logo dynamic.

here is my code (displaying logo) which is in header.php page:

```
<a  href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" title="">
</a>
```

***** when I want to change it from Customize > Site Identity, here it shows that no logo is attached, yet the logo is displaying successfully at front-end. Even when I try to change it, nothing happens.

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme header logo function `get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );`

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
echo '<img class="header_logo" src="'.$image[0].'">';
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing ur great answer. There is some design issue, i.e. the logo is displaying too large. May I need to change the img css only or there is/are something new function/parameter available to do this ??

Comment: either scale the image to exact dimensions and re-upload, or at least make sure the proportions are exactly what you want then do then rest with CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
```

Just change the 'full' to 'thumbnail' or something else. You can also [define](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) custom sizes.
Or you could target it by the class 'header_logo' in css.

Comment: Many many many many thanx to you. Your suggestion "thumbnail" saves my valuable time. May be this was the code I was looking for. thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code in header.php :**

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="">
```

**Then open site wp-admin :**
Go to apperence -> customize -> Header Image and upload logo  and publish it